# Ik bones in makehuman models

Tags: rigging, bones, makehuman

I am using makehuman 1.1.0 and blender 2.77a. I am able to use rigged human models as mhx2 file exported from makehuman. In makehuman I am using the default rig. The models however dont have the Ik bones. Would it be possible for makehuman to generate rigged model with Ik bones and thus easy controls ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but i suppose there is no such way. As long as the model does not already have an IK contraint in make human, it is more as unlikely that in blender it should got one. and even if it has ik in make human (im not very familiar with make human) there is no guarantee that it will export to blender.

Comment: But you can easily add your own ik contraints to the exportet rig. it is really not that hard. just watch some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Demons. As it turns out that makhuman does support ik bones. But to load them, you need to override exported data with proper options while importing mhx2 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I did find solution. It was under my nose all this time. While in **pose mode** Under **tools section** we have an option to switch to IK bones. Ik bones does help making things easy.

[image]

Comment: Several days I was searching that !